# Clicking on status-completed in StackOverflow Meta opens a search result page to StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

When I click on the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag on StackOverflow Meta, it opens a search result page to StackOverflow.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. `[tag:]` is for tags on the *main* site. `[meta-tag:]` is for tags on the Meta site.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) vs [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: +1 Oh, I didn't know that.